# My plotting comes out to be gray not coloured using AbsArgPlot function in Mathematica. What is the reason for not getting a coloured graph??h

Tags: complex, interpolation, scripting, computational-complexity

My graph comes out to be gray, not coloured using `AbsArgPlot` function in **Mathematica**. What is the reason for not getting a coloured graph or what I can deduce from it about the complex function that I considered.
Basically I am using a complex Lagrange interpolating polynomial.
I am including the graph.
The `Exp[z]` gives a good coloured graph given below.

```
z = Cos[j] + I*Sin[j];

AbsArgPlot[{Exp[z]}, {j, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

The interpolating polynomial that I created using the nodes on the unit circle produces the below graph which comes out to be gray.

```
z = Cos[j] + I*Sin[j];

AbsArgPlot[{LR}, {j, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Axis]
```

,

where LR is the interpolatory polynomial I created.
[image]
My interpolating polynomial approximates Exp[z] nicely as the graph turns out to be similar. but what can I deduce with this gray colour coming .

Comment: Hi VARUN! Can you, please, provide for us the definition of `LR`? You reference it is an interpolation, but you have not given the definition of this interpolation, which is essential for the solution of this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is meant to be an extensive comment.

The main point is that there might be an issue with the definition of LR in your code. The reason that I am suggesting this, is that I tried to plot an interpolating polynomial and `AbsArgPlot` works fine. Let me show you what I have tried.

To begin with, I have taken the definition of the Lagrange interpolation from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221173/lagrange-interpolation)

We have

```
lagrangeInterpolation[values_, var_] := 
 Module[{xvalues = values\[Transpose][[1, All]], 
   yvalues = values\[Transpose][[2, All]], subs, complements, 
   nominators, denominators}, 
  subs = Subsets[xvalues, {Length@xvalues - 1}];
  complements = Flatten[Complement[xvalues, #] & /@ subs];
  nominators = Times @@ (# - x) & /@ subs;
  denominators = 
   Table[Times @@ (subs[[i]] - complements[[i]]), {i, 1, Length@subs}];
  Reverse[nominators/denominators].yvalues]
```

Ok, so now my logic is quite simple. Create a list of data points `{x,y}`. Not that for the y-points I have used your expression $e^z=e^{\cos j + i \sin j}$

```
xvalues = Join[{0}, Range@6]
yvalues = Table[Exp[Cos[j] + I*Sin[j]], {j, 0, 2 Pi}] // N
data = Transpose[{xvalues, yvalues}];
```

Since we have a a way of obtaining the Lagrange polynomial we can use

```
poly = Expand[lagrangeInterpolation[data, x]]
```

and then we can plot

```
AbsArgPlot[{poly}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Axis]
```

which gives

[image]

As it has already been pointed out it would be very helpful to give us the expression for the LR that you used.

Edit: following the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsArgPlot.html) I think that the best way to understand the different colours is the following

```
AbsArgPlot[{poly}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

and observe what you get next to your plot

Comment: I cannot provide the code for LR since I am using it my research problem i.e unpublished work. I am just vertically projecting the zeros of  Legendre Polynomial of n degree on to the unit circle using transformation ((z+(z)^-1)/2 . LR is just the complex Lagrange polynomial on these 2n nodes. I only wanted to know what does these colours represent in the AbsArgPlot. and what does it mean if someone is not getting coloured graph, then what we can interpret about the function or argument .anything.I just want deductions on the base of the graph. Thank You

Comment: No need to thank me. I hope you will be able to modify appropriately and get your desired result.

Comment: can you please tell the significance of the colours in AbsArgPlot. What they represent.

Comment: I added a comment to the post by following the documentation. I hope it is clear now. I have also provided a link where you can find more details